# What is the best way to tidily append many columns?

Tags: r

I'm looking to append 30 columns which give values for gamma distributions by using the tidyverse. Here's an example of the data:

```
data.frame('rank'=1:3,'shape'=c(16,0.2,4),'rate'=c(13,0.4,0.2))
```

I'd like to use `dgamma(1:30,shape,rate)` to append 30 columns to the existing dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map2()` in `purrr` and `unnest_wider()` in `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(density = map2(shape, rate, dgamma, x = 1:30)) %>%
  unnest_wider(density, names_sep = "_")
```

Or use `rowwise()` at first and then `mutate()` with `list()`.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(density = list(dgamma(1:30, shape, rate))) %>%
  unnest_wider(density, names_sep = "_")
```

Both of them give

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 33
#    rank shape  rate density_1 density_2 density_3 density_4 density_5 density_6 density_7
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1  16    13    1.15       0.0852  0.0000843   1.43e-8  9.16e-13  3.19e-17  7.28e-22
# 2     2   0.2   0.4  0.122      0.0468  0.0227      1.21e-2  6.77e- 3  3.92e- 3  2.32e- 3
# 3     3   4     0.2  0.000218   0.00143 0.00395     7.67e-3  1.23e- 2  1.73e- 2  2.26e- 2
# # … with 23 more variables: density_8 <dbl>, density_9 <dbl>, density_10 <dbl>, ..., density_30 <dbl>
```